# why POST method is not working?

Tags: php

I have do post some information in cross domain . And i am achieving this thing by below code

```
<?php

  function do_post_request($sendingurl, $data, $optional_headers = null) {

    $params = array(
      'http' => array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'url' => $data
      )
    );
    if ($optional_headers !== null) {
      $params['http']['header'] = $optional_headers;
    }
    $ctx = stream_context_create($params);

    $fp = @fopen($sendingurl, 'rb', false, $ctx);
    if (!$fp) {
      throw new Exception("Problem with $sendingurl, $php_errormsg");
    }

    $response = @stream_get_contents($fp);
    if ($response === false) {
      throw new Exception("Problem reading data from $sendingurl, $php_errormsg");
    }

    return $response;

  }

  $response = do_post_request('http://mag16.playtrickz.com/testing.php','http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com');
  echo $response;
```

But it is not working . 
On successful POST Request : It will display its value 
otherwise it will show : **nodata found**.
Why it is not working and how to make them work .

Comment: "Not working" does not tell us much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I would write your function:

```
function do_post_request($url, $data = NULL, $optional_headers = NULL) {

  // Build a body string from an array
  $content = (is_array($data)) ? http_build_query($data) : '';

  // Parse the array of headers and strip values we will be setting
  $headers = array();
  if (is_array($optional_headers)) {
    foreach ($optional_headers as $name => $value) {
      if (!in_array(strtolower($name), array('content-type', 'content-length', 'connection'))) {
        $headers[$name] = $value;
      }
    }
  }

  // Add our pre-set headers
  $headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
  $headers['Content-Length'] = strlen($content);
  $headers['Connection'] = 'close';

  // Build headers into a string
  $header = array();
  foreach ($headers as $name => $value) {
    if (is_array($value)) {
      foreach ($value as $multi) {
        $header[] = "$name: $multi";
      }
    } else {
      $header[] = "$name: $value";
    }
  }
  $header = implode("\r\n", $header);

  // Create the stream context
  $params = array(
    'http' => array(
      'method' => 'POST',
      'header' => $header,
      'content' => $content
    )
  );
  $ctx = stream_context_create($params);

  // Make the request
  $fp = @fopen($url, 'rb', FALSE, $ctx);
  if (!$fp) {
    throw new Exception("Problem with $url, $php_errormsg");
  }

  $response = @stream_get_contents($fp);
  if ($response === FALSE) {
    throw new Exception("Problem reading data from $url, $php_errormsg");
  }

  return $response;

}
```

This has been re-built so that the data to send to the server and the headers are passed in as associative arrays. So you would build an array that looks like you would want `$_POST` to look in the remote script, and pass that in. You can also pass an array of additional headers to send, but the function will automatically add a `Content-Type`, `Content-Length` and `Connection` header.

So your request would be called like this:

```
$data = array(
  'url' => 'http://www.facebook.com/'
);
$response = do_post_request('http://mag16.playtrickz.com/testing.php', $data);
echo $response;
```